# How to repeat forward and backward solve using cuSolver by CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cusolver

Recently I developed a new method. The new method works perfect with CUDA (at 20 to 40FPS) and I have already tested it successfully. The problem comes when I try to make a comparison with an old method.  The old method was implemented on CPU. It does LU decomposition **A**=**LU** first, and then runs forward+back steps to solve (**LU**)**x**=**b**. The very nice thing about the old method is that **A** does not change, so LU decomposition can be done only once and the overhead is just the forward+backward solve. **A** is **sparse** and **symmetric positive definite**. (*I believe this is a fairly common practice in many problems, e.g., fluid simulation in a fixed domain.*)

To make my comparison fair, I want to implement the old method on GPU. But I didn't find any sparse LU decomposition in cuSolver or cuSparse.  Am I supposed to calculate it by some other libraries?  Shall I use cusolverRfSolve() for solve? If so, why **L** and **U** are not input, but **P** and **Q** are input to this function? Is there any working example similar to what I am trying to do?

Even if the old method runs slower on GPU, I would love to see it, which makes my new method really useful.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, it looks like the intended use of `cusolverRfSolve` requires the following previous calls:

- `cusolverRfCreate`
- `cusolverRfSetup[Host/Device]` <-- this takes as input already a matrix `L`, `U`, `P` and `Q`
- `cusolverRfAnalyze`
- `cusolverRfRefactor`

and then you only call `cusolverRfSolve` (again with `P` and `Q`). The previous calls analyse the given matrices and determine the parallelism strategy.

Given the examples from the cuSOLVER documentation, it looks like they intentionally outsourced the LU factorisation, so you need to provide the factorised matrices to the library.

I am currently working on interfacing scipy in python (`scipy.sparse.linalg.splu`) with cuSOLVER in order to provide the LU factorisation `Pr * A * Pc = L * U`. cuSOLVER will need `P = Pr.T` and `Q = Pc.T`. You can use the `cusolverRfSetupHost` function to let cuSOLVER take care of GPU memory allocation and transfer.

Alternatively one could make use of suitesparse (http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) in C++.